# C sockets send & recv

Tags: c, sockets, server, send, recv

I'm coding a multi-client server and I don't understand why my code is not working.
I'm trying to send a message from the server to a client, but the second one never arrived or is equal to a random huge number...

**An example of what I can obtain:**

> The server send that data : You have reached the server!
>
> checkNewMessage
>
> New message is : 545952912

You can see my code bellow:

**Client Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


int isEnd(char response[256]) {
    return (response == "a");
}

char *checkNewMessage(int server_socket)
{
    int i = 0;
    int received;
    //char *server_response;
    char *full_server_response = NULL;
    char server_response[256];

    printf("Check some new message\n");
    recv(server_socket, &server_response,sizeof(server_response),0);
    printf("message is %d:\n",server_response);

    //server_response = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
    full_server_response = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
    printf("Here;\n");
    *full_server_response = '\0';
    do {
        printf("Nice\n");
        *server_response = '\0';
        received = recv(server_socket, server_response,sizeof(server_response),0);
        if (received > 0){
            strcat(full_server_response, strcat(server_response, " "));
        }
    } while (received > 0);
    return full_server_response;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    //create a socket
    int network_socket;
    network_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);

    //specify an address for the socket
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    int connect_status = connect(network_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address,sizeof(server_address));
    //check for error during the connexion
    if (connect_status == -1) {
        printf("There were an error during the connetion to the remote socket\n\n");
    }
    else {
        //Set the server socket in non blocking state
        //fcntl(network_socket, F_SETFL, fcntl(network_socket, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);
        //receive data from the server
        char server_response[256];
        recv(network_socket, &server_response,sizeof(server_response),0);

        //print out the server's response
        printf("The server send that data : %s\n\n",server_response);
        int k = 1;
        while (k--) {
            //here get the response of the server...
            printf("checkNewMessage\n");
            recv(network_socket, &server_response,sizeof(server_response),0);
            printf("New message is : %d\n",server_response);
            //printf("New message = %s\n",checkNewMessage(network_socket));
        }

        //close the socket
        close(network_socket);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Server Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>

void killAllConnetions(int clients_sockets[])
{
    for (int i=0;i<2;i++) {
        send(clients_sockets[i], "a", sizeof("a"),0);
        close(clients_sockets[i]);
    }
}

void transmitMessageToAll(int clients_sockets[],char* client_msg,int n)
{
    printf("Transmit the following message : %s\n",client_msg);
    printf("Client socket: %d\n",clients_sockets[0]);
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        if (i>0){
            send(clients_sockets[i], client_msg, sizeof(client_msg),0);
        }
    }
}

char *checkNewMessage(int clients_sockets[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int received;
    char *client_response = NULL;
    char *full_client_response = NULL;

    client_response = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
    full_client_response = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));


    do {
        *full_client_response = '\0';
        do {
            *client_response = '\0';
            received = recv(clients_sockets[i], client_response,sizeof(client_response),0);
            if (received > 0){
                strcat(full_client_response, strcat(client_response, " "));
            }
        } while (received > 0);
        i++;
    } while ((i<3) && (*full_client_response == '\0'));
    return full_client_response;
}

int addNewClient(int server_socket)
{
    int newClient;

    listen(server_socket,5);
    newClient = accept(server_socket,NULL, NULL);

    return newClient;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    char server_msg[256] = "You have reached the server!";

    //create a socket
    int server_socket;
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    fcntl(server_socket, F_SETFL, fcntl(server_socket, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);

    //define the server address
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    //bind the socket to our specified IP and port
    bind(server_socket,(struct sockaddr*) &server_address,sizeof(server_address));

    //create a list of 2 clients
    int clients_sockets[3];
    int i = 0;
    while (i<3) {
        //add new client
        clients_sockets[i] = addNewClient(server_socket);
        if (clients_sockets[i] != -1) {
            printf("In main socket: %d\n",clients_sockets[i]);
            fcntl(clients_sockets[i], F_SETFL, fcntl(clients_sockets[i], F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);
            //send the welcome message
            send(clients_sockets[i], server_msg, sizeof(server_msg),0);
            send(clients_sockets[i], "Second message", sizeof(server_msg),0);
            i++;
        }
        if (i > 0) {
          send(clients_sockets[i], server_msg, sizeof(server_msg),0);
          printf("Client connected\n");
        }

        sleep(1);
        //receive data from client
        printf("message = %s\n",checkNewMessage(clients_sockets));
        //transmitMessageToAll(clients_sockets,checkNewMessage(clients_sockets),i);
        transmitMessageToAll(clients_sockets,"Test",i);
    }

    //close all clients sockets
    killAllConnetions(clients_sockets);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot

PS: I also get sometimes : *connect_status == -1*

Comment: You need the `%s` conversion specifier here:  `printf("message is %s:\n",server_response);` In the future, compile with compiler-flag `-Wall`, which would have exactly told you the cause of your issue (and one more issue, too, btw)

Comment: Given the function `void transmitMessageToAll(int clients_sockets[],char* client_msg,int n)`, just what do you think `sizeof(client_msg)` is?

Comment: `send(clients_sockets[i], server_msg, sizeof(server_msg),0);` ---> `send(clients_sockets[i], server_msg, strlen(server_msg)+1,0);`

Comment: This is not correct, too: `send(clients_sockets[i], "a", sizeof("a"),0);`. You need `strlen("a")` here

Comment: Hm, the string terminator is not necessarily (usually?) sent over the network.

Comment: It’s still not working but i’m on it

Comment: @Ctx I don't understand why I need to put  `send(clients_sockets[i], server_msg, strlen(server_msg)+1,0);` and not `send(clients_sockets[i], server_msg, sizeof(server_msg),0);` . Because sizeof(server_msg) give me 256 and strlen: 28. So I have not the entire message with strlen...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204450/discussion-between-dusart-victor-and-ctx).